# time code with hundredths?

Tags: javascript, seconds, timecodes

Been creating a time code format from decimal seconds but now need to get hundredths into the format.

so for 1.5 secs i need to get 00:00:01:050 but i need some help as not getting anywhere!

Any help appreciated... D.

```
function secondsToTime(secs) {

    var hours = Math.floor(secs / (60 * 60));

    var divisor_for_minutes = secs % (60 * 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor(divisor_for_minutes / 60);

    var divisor_for_seconds = divisor_for_minutes % 60;
    var seconds = Math.ceil(divisor_for_seconds);

    // guesswork! 
    var divisor_for_hund = divisor_for_seconds / 100;
    var hund = divisor_for_hund;

    var obj = {
        "tc": pad(hours, 2) + ':' + pad(minutes, 2) + ':' + pad(seconds, 2)+ ':' + pad(hund, 3),
        "h": pad(hours, 2),
        "m": pad(minutes, 2),
        "s": pad(seconds, 2)
    };
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: What do you get now? In other words, what's the problem?

Comment: 1.5 seconds would be "00:00:01:500". You have written "00:00:01:050" which is 1.05 seconds. Also, it seems you want _milliseconds_ (thousands of a second) - not hundreds. If it were hundreds, it'd be only 2 decimals.

Comment: Was getting lots of mixed results! Hundreds or thousands is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var hundredths = Math.round((secs % 1) * 100);
```

`secs % 1` will make `0.5` from `1.5` or `0.456` from `123.456` and when you multiply that by `100`, you get the number of hundredths you want to display. Then just round the result.

Update: It was pointed out you probably want ms. Just put `1000` in place of the `100`.